# ClassCastException: org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignatureFactory cannot be cast to class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory

Tags: java, wso2, mediator, ei

I'm using `WSO2` `EI ver 6.6.0` , and I developed a mediator which is responsible for Signing SOAP Envelopes.

The code I'm using correctly works on Java SE, and I've tested it. But when I compile it and deploy it on the `WSO2 EI`, it's not working.

The code has been thrown from this part of the code.

```java
private static Document sign(Document doc, String Reference) throws Exception {
    DOMSignContext dsc = null;
    String providerName = System.getProperty("jsr105Provider", "org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI");
    Provider provider = (Provider) Class.forName(providerName).newInstance();

    // Below line throw exception!
    XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM", provider);

    .
    .
    .
    return doc;
}
```

Error

```java
java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignatureFactory cannot be cast to class javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory (org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMXMLSignatureFactory is in module java.xml.crypto of loader 'platform'; javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @657e3cda)
        at javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory.findInstance(XMLSignatureFactory.java:202)
        at javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance(XMLSignatureFactory.java:250)
        at x.signer.util.Utils.sign(Utils.java:246)
        at x.signer.util.Utils.insertSignSoap(Utils.java:233)
        at x.signer.util.Utils.insertSignSayad(Utils.java:197)
        at x.signer.Signer.mediate(Signer.java:37)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.ext.ClassMediator.mediate(ClassMediator.java:94)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:109)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:331)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:441)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcess(RESTRequestHandler.java:135)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:113)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:71)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:327)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:98)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:368)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:427)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:182)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Example of input

```xml
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <InquiryCode xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <RequestCode>12345</RequestCode>
        </InquiryCode>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I searched lots of similar issues and Stackoverflow questions, but most of them are unanswered, or the answered ones are not working for me like this one:

https://groups.google.com/g/fusefabric/c/1no0A5akFag

[How to fix ClassCastException when XMLSignatureFactory used in a WSO2-AM Mediator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56215745/how-to-fix-classcastexception-when-xmlsignaturefactory-used-in-a-wso2-am-mediato)

Comment: Did you try creating an OSGI bundle and isolating the problematic dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Bundle the required javax.xml.crypto class jar inside the class mediator.

To do this, you must create a class mediator as an OSGI bundle rather than a jar file. If you have the following in your class mediator project pom.xml file;

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Change this to;

```
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
```

Following that, bundle the javax.xml.crypto class jar to the class mediator. To do this, add the following to the class mediator pom.xml file under **maven-bundle-plugin** as shown below.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
       -----------


       -----------------------
        <Import-Package>
              *; resolution:=optional
          </Import-Package>
          <Embed-Dependency>
        javax.xml.crypto.dsig
          </Embed-Dependency>
          <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
      </instructions>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Now build the class mediator and add the created jar file /dropins folder. Make sure you remove the previous class mediator jar from both /lib and /dropins folder.

Restart the server after adding the class mediator.

Comment: Thanks Nadun for your answer, I've done step by step what you said multiple time. But still get the same error. Do you have any other opinion?